# Why do VBA CurrentProject.Connection statements cause all my access databases to crash?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working with a legacy database .mdb database that just crashes in Access 2007 when it hits lines with CurrentProject.Connection in them.

When I add the same code to **brand new databases** it crashes them too.

```
Dim rstDateFields As New adodb.Recordset
rstDateFields.Open "SELECT * FROM defDateFields ORDER BY FieldID", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

References set to: VBA, MS ACCESS 12.0 object library, OLE automation, MS Ofrfice 14.0 Access db engine object

Comment: Have you been able to run the select statement directly?

Comment: Did the application work previously with this code, or did the error occur only after updates to the code?

Comment: Here are the details : http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm

Comment: Is the `CurrentProject.Connection` open when this code executes?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I think you're on to something. If I put a break on that line, the code stops. But if I try to mouse over CurrentProject.Connection (I was going to see if a tool tip would tell me it was open) then the database crashes.

Comment: Take a look at [How To Open ADO Connection and Recordset Objects](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168336) for a checklist of what can open a connection.

Comment: Also if Office has been updated recently, there is some remote possibility that it could be an issue. [Access 2007 Crashes with ADODB Recordset](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=201886).

Comment: Also check to make sure that everything is declared as described in the first answer to [Access 2007 Recordset Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559827/access-2007-recordset-problem).

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Again, I think you're on to something. This is an old mdb database that we are running in Access 2007

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I changed all of the currentProject.Connection.Executes to CurrentDb.Execute's. This solved the problem. Thanks for your help.  You got me most of the way there. I changed the question so that it will be helpful to others. If you want to answer, I will accept. Otherwise, I will write it up in a few days http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t1957584.html

Comment: Have you determined this problem is more generalized than the original version of this question which described crashes when opening an ADO recorset based on a query of defDateFields?  Does it happen any time you reference `CurrentProject.Connection`?  Does it also happen with similar operations in a new database file?

Comment: @HansUp It happens every time I reference CurrentProject.Connection. I changed the question to address this general error (which other people will probably have)--rather than just asking, hey, why is this specific procedure in my db not working

Comment: In that one database or all your db files from that machine?  If you add this line to a procedure, does it also crash Access? `Debug.Print CurrentProject.Connection`  If it doesn't crash Access, do you get a reasonable OleDb connection string for the current db file?

Comment: @HansUp nice call. that code crashes all Access databases. does that mean something to you?

Comment: Yes it means you should next determine whether the problem is isolated to that one machine.  Try the same code from a different machine.

Comment: @HansUp the problem is isolated on one machine. the code runs fine on another machine. thanks for the help

Comment: That makes sense.  The code you showed us was very basic ADO ... hard to believe the code itself was the problem.  Unfortunately it may be challenging to figure out how that machine is broken.  Fully patched Windows and Office?  Any update failures?  If it becomes too time-consuming and frustrating trying to find and fix the problem, you can re-install instead.

Comment: @HansUp : I feel like that is a good answer (i.e. it's basic ado, theres something wrong with your machine). If you want to answer that, i will accept. Luckily, I dont need to use this DB, so I am not going to worry about fixing my machine right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed us was very basic ADO, so it's hard to believe the code itself is the cause of the problem. Check whether the problem is isolated to that one machine by trying the same code from another machine.  If it runs without error there, mostly likely the original machine is broken somehow.  Unfortunately trying to find and fix the breakage can be challenging.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. The code runs well on other machines, so it is probably a problem with my particular computer--not the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

One guess: could you make sure that your recordset is of the ADO type? Are you using an implicit declaration for your recordset, such as "Dim rs as recordset"? In this case your recordset could be of the DAO type.

And anyway we'd love to help you but you should give us some more code to understand your problem!

Comment: I agree. I would implicit decleare the recordset. Just a few more wee lines of code may very well help resolve this case.